# Writing a friend a birthday wish in Italian...?

Tags: translation, phrase-request, english-comparison, sentences, phrase-choice

I'm writing my Italian friend a birthday card and wanted to write

*'May today and all your days be full of wonderful adventures, creative energy, and many occasions to toast to.'*

which I translated (with the help of google) to:

*Possa oggi e tutti i tuoi giorni essere pieno di avventure meravigliose, energia creativa e molte occasioni per brindare!*

I feel that some of the meaning might have been lost in translation. Would 'ti auguro' be more appropriate in place of 'Possa'?

Thank you to everyone in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

> Possano oggi e tutti i tuoi giorni essere pieni di avventure meravigliose, energia creativa e molte occasioni per brindare!

(Google missed some singular/plural agreements.)

As for *possa* or *ti auguro*, the former translates your “may...”. *Ti auguro...* is instead more on the lines of “I wish you...” and indeed sounds a bit more usual. In this case, the sentence could be:

> Ti auguro che oggi e tutti i tuoi giorni siano pieni di avventure meravigliose, energia creativa e molte occasioni per brindare!